# How to turn off snap api service?

Tags: snap

I wanted to try django and when I did `sudo lsof -i:8000` I got this:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 1172 root    5u  IPv4  50529      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
python3 2251 root    5u  IPv4  50529      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
python3 2252 root    5u  IPv4  50529      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
```

and on http://127.0.0.1:8000 I got this:

```
snapcraft.io store API service - Copyright 2018-2021 Canonical.
```

So how do I get rid of this?

PS: I don't want to uninstall snap and I know there's a workaround by changing django port. But the question is how to change snap api service port , or , turn it off, without completely uninstall snap.

Comment: Well the usual way is to uninstall Snap Store. However, you can also simply change Django's port. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639085/django-change-default-runserver-port)

Comment: Yeah, but I am wondering whether it's possible to just close the service.

Comment: On my 22.10 Desktop, snap-store has no listener on port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

you can try django in port 7000

```
python manage.py runserver 7000
```

Comment: Thanks , But I still want to use port 8000, i.e for other purposes.